# Starting selenium grid through java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, grid

I'm starting Selenium grid with below java code,

```
GridHubConfiguration config = new GridHubConfiguration();
config.setHost("localhost");
config.setPort(5555);
Hub hub = new Hub(config);
try {
    hub.start();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

And when I open `http://localhost:5555/grid/console` the page just opens perfectly and if I click on "view config" link on the page it throws error as below:-

> HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing `/grid/console`.

> Reason: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to
> java.lang.Integer. And I am using version 2.44.0.

I am not sure what's causing the issue. Can somebody point me what's wrong with above code.

Comment: I bet the stack trace would reveal which line of code and which class is causing it.  Can you provide stack trace in your question?

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue? I'm trying to setup Grid and register nodes through java program and looking for similar answer as well.